# Getting all IPs of devices connected to the same router

Tags: networking, ip

I have several linux devices connected to the same router (of which I am not a administrator). How can I find out the ip addresses of all other devices by executing some commands in one of them?

Comment: related (with links to a lot of duplicate quesions): [How can I list all IPs in the connected network, through Terminal preferably?](http://superuser.com/q/261818/210781)

Comment: If this is a router and not a switch, I'm not sure if you can. A router doesn't pass broadcasts by default, and each device might be on a different subnet, so arp/nmap/fing/ping might be useless.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you could use `nmap` to get such information.

The below command lists me all the machines/devices connected in my network. It is a home network and it lists me all the machines in my home.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

I believe you need to modify the subnet mask and IP range that you are in to suit your requirements.

Comment: why 192.168.1.0/24? what means?

Comment: `nmap -sA 192.168.1.0/24`  nmap option `-sA` shows similar descriptive results with better readability, which includes device name, IP, mac, etc as with option `-sP`. I personally  prefer `-sA` over `-sP` for the readability sake.

Comment: @Tarlo_x https://superuser.com/questions/970380/so-what-does-24-have-to-do-with-255-in-hosts-ip-addresses

Answer (score 2):

For a more compact list of connected devices:

```
nmap -sL 192.168.0.* | grep \(1
```

**Explanation**
`nmap -sL 192.168.0.*` will list all IPs in subnetwork and mark those, that have name:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.0
Nmap scan report for Dlink-Router.Dlink (192.168.0.1)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.2
...
Nmap scan report for android-473e80f183648322.Dlink (192.168.0.53)
...
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.255
```

As all interesting records contain parenthesis `(` and digit `1`, we filter for that with `| grep \(1` (backslash is needed to escape parenthesis)

**Quirk**
Beware that if two devices have the same name, `nmap` will show only the one, that was connected to router *last*